# How to perform a task when user closed app flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to detect when a user quit my app and execute some code before but I don't know how to do this. I tried so many packages but did not get any solution I just want to execute a Firestore function when the app was closed

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you should use Widgetbinding observer here is the sample code :

```
    class Demo extends State with WidgetsBindingObserver{

    AppLifecycleState state;

    @override
    void initState() {
       // TODO: implement initState
       super.initState();

       WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
     }

     @override
     void dispose() {
       // TODO: implement dispose
       super.dispose();

       WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
     }


     @override
     void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
       super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
     
       /// STATES : inactive , paused , resumed , detached

       if(state == AppLifecycleState.inactive){
          /// Insert your code here
       }
     }


      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(

          body:Text("Obersever"));

      }}
```

this will work for you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you want to call a Firestore function when the user kills your app or closes the app totally. You can do that in your app lifecycle when the state is `inactive` see below example:

```
@override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
     if(state == AppLifecycleState.inactive){
      // app is inactive
      firestoreFunction();

    }
  }
```